# CSV File as ASCII and with CRLF

Tags: php, csv, ascii

I need a CRLF (char10,char(13) for each line in my csv file. The samples i found are not properly working. And i need the file in ASCII not UTF8. How can i save it as ASCII?

My code:

```
$fp = fopen('import.csv', 'w');

while ($daten = pg_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    fputcsv($fp,$daten,chr(9));
}
```

Comment: Are you on windows? If so, perhaps adding the 't' mode to fopen will help. See the note following the mode table  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php for a discussion on line endings on different systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldnt need to manually put a CRLF at the end of each line when using fputcsv

However if you do actually want an "extra" line in between rows you could try this:

```
    $fp = fopen('import.csv', 'w');  
    while ($daten = pg_fetch_assoc($query)) 
    {     
    fputcsv($fp,$daten,chr(9)); 
    fputs($fp,'\n');
    } 
    fclose($fp);
```

Note that this is for linux ascii, if you want windows ascii it is '\r\n'

Comment: I need at the end of every line a "\r\n". Im creating the csv on an linux system so i only have an "\n" of every line using fputcsv?

Comment: Yes, the unix ascii system only puts in \n, it is only windows systems that require \r\n - As a result if you put in something along the lines of $file = file_get_contents('import.csv'); $file =preg_replace("~(?<!\r)\n~","\r\n",$file ); file_put_contents('import.csv', $file); at the end of that script this will give the effect for windows systems crlf